# how to get date in c# in the format like "27Aug13"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

In c# , date should be displayed as "27Aug13" .can anyone suggest how to achieve that format?

Please help,Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

use `ToString()`

```
string strDate = dateVar.ToString("ddMMMyy");
```

where `datevar` holds your `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 1):

try `datetime.ToString("ddMMMyy")`

Reference : [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyy");
```

Checkout *[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)*

To customise the localisation (eg. language for month abbreviation) use a [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ToString.aspx) overload that also takes an [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For 27 use [`dd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier) format, for AUG use [`MMM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier) format, for 13 use [`yy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yySpecifier) format.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string s = date.ToString("ddMMMyy");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/14GkCq).

For more custom format, you should look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)